# Registering Spring beans without Component Scanning

Tags: spring

I have `MySimpleController` and I need to extract this controller to a common library.

```
package xxx.mypackage;

@Controller
class MySimpleController{}
```

This library has a different package name, `yyy.newpackage` which is different than previous `xxx.mypackage`. Because of this, It is not suitable for component scanning.

Here is the question: Is there a way to register this controller without component scanning? I just want to include my jar and expecting my controller properly. I have seen some definitions in `META-INF` folder but could not be sure that this is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Create configuration for whole 3rd party library

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfig {

    @Bean
    public MySimpleController mySimpleController(){
        return new MySimpleController();
    }
}
```

and import this configuration without scanning

```
@Import(CustomConfig.class)
```

My sample is in JavaConfig, but this apply to xml configuration too.

Comment: I want to import automatically.

Comment: Wonderful. this is a better solution

Comment: @Cemo automatically without scanning? :)

Comment: @MariuszS, exactly. :)

Comment: @Cemo what do you mean by registering without component scanning?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

Answer (score 0):

add this controller as a bean with the new package in your applicationCOntext. By doing so, it would be the only bean loaded through the xml config whereas everything else is through your component scan.

```
<beans>
    <bean name="myBean" class="yy.MySimpleController"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: This requires change at my users configuration. I want that my jar will be included and It will work without any manual registration.

Comment: Well, if you are moving this out as a jar file, is somebody going to use this jar file as a dependency? If so, wouldnt they be using your MySimpleController as a dependency in the code?

Comment: Yes, it will be used as a dependency. MySimpleController is fully functional code, other pieces does not interact with this controller. Consider it as a controller providing some system information.